# VB.Net there's an Exception Unhandled when I clear out PriceTxt just because the DiscountTxt doesn't get the value

Tags: vb.net, textbox

My problem here is that whenever I put a Value Price on the PriceTxt the DiscountTxt will compute for its discount but when I clear out the PriceTxt it gets an Exception saying "Conversion from String "" to type 'Double' is not valid". I tried getting the logical if statement that if the PriceTxt.Text = "" The DiscountTxt will set back to 0 which means no value to be computed.

```
 Dim percentage As Decimal = 0.1
    If PriceTxt.MaxLength > 11 Then
        DiscountTxt.Text = (PriceTxt.Text * percentage)
        DiscountTxt.Text = PriceTxt.Text - DiscountTxt.Text
    End If

    If PriceTxt.Text = "" Then
        DiscountTxt.ResetText()
    End If
```

Nah couldn't think of Else if and Else on it since it doesn't work either.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: What event is this code running in?

Comment: PriceTxt_TextChanged.

Comment: That is not the best place to run the code. For example, suppose you are entering 75. The code would run on the 7 and then the 75. Kind of wasteful. Can you add a button called CalculateDiscount and put the code in the click event.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking at `MaxLength` instead of `Length` here.

Here's another way to do that, using `TryParse`.  It returns `True` IF it was able to squeeze the value into the target.  Please see `prc` as the first.

```
 Dim percentage As Decimal = 0.1
 Dim prc as Decimal

    If decimal.TryParse(PriceTxt.Text, prc) then 'puts it in a double, if it is.
        DiscountTxt.Text = (prc * percentage)
        Dim discount as Decimal
        If decimal.TryParse(DiscountTxt.Text, discount) Then
           DiscountTxt.Text = prc - discount 'Or is this a total box?
        End If  

    End If

    If PriceTxt.Text = "" Then
        DiscountTxt.ResetText()
    End If
```